# Alternate text area?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, textarea, text-editor

The `<TEXTAREA>` HTML tag is dull and does not give any editing options. The question is: is there an alternate, easily integrated controller that the client can edit code in and it returns a string with the same writing, encoded into HTML? And if there is, how can I integrate it into my website? (in my case it is C# ASP.NET based)

Comment: you need to find a WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Are you thinking something like this?  http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

Comment: All the html tag does is denote that its content should be legitimate html. Does it need to be more exciting than that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the contenteditable attribute in HTML5 which lets you edit tags such as `<p>` or `<h1>`
Example:

```
<p contenteditable="contenteditable">hello!</p>
```

Comment: wasn't quite what i was looking for. i am looking for a textarea-like input that has basic text editing options- such as bolding, italic, font change Etc...